# NAnt - Get filename in folder that contains specific word

Tags: c#, nant

I ran into a situation where it would be easier to get the filename within a directory of a file that contains a specific naming format. The middle for the file name never changes but the beginning and end can change.

For example of the middle "_ProjectName_Release_Patch_" . Is there a way for me to check if a file that as a name like that in the directory using NAnt? If a file does have that name, get the `filename`?

Similar to the SQL LIKE command? `%_ProjectName_Release_Patch_%`

Comment: Maybe `fileName.Contains("_ProjectName_Release_Patch_")` or `fileName.IndexOf("_ProjectName_Release_Patch_", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0`

Comment: Regexs are not working?

Comment: I guess regex would work in this situation. Thanks for the suggestion I will post my solution using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For lack of a better solution, this did the trick for me. Thanks !

```html
  <property name="pattern" value="_ProjectName_Release_Patch_" />
  
  <echo message="Looking..." />
  
    <foreach item="File" property="file">
         <in>         
            <items>
               <include name="${Folder}\**.sql" />
            </items>
         </in>
         <do>
   <property name="FILE" value="" />
   <echo message="Looking for a match of: ${pattern}" />
   <regex pattern="(?'FILE'${pattern}.*)" input="${file}" failonerror="false" />

    <if test="${string::get-length(FILE) > 0}">
    <echo message="match: ${FILE}" />
      <property name="file.path" value="${file}" />
    </if>
   </do>
 </foreach>
 
 <property name="PatternFile" value="${file.path}" />
 <echo message="The file path is :${PatternFile}" />
```